# AWS S3: IA vs One-Zone IA Storage Classes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon announced on April 2018 the availability of a new storage class, named One-Zone Infrequent Access, that complements the plain IA option by lowering the cost via the usage of only one AZ for storage.

Its [site](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/announcing-s3-one-zone-infrequent-access-a-new-amazon-s3-storage-class/), advertises that **all** storage classes have the so-called 11 9s durability.

My question is how two options (IA vs One Zone IA) can have the same (i.e. 11 9s) durability, given that the later uses 1 AZ (vs multiple of the former)

> Amazon S3 Standard, S3 Standard-IA, S3 One Zone-IA, and Amazon
>   Glacier, are all designed for 99.999999999% durability. Amazon S3
>   Standard, S3 Standard-IA and Amazon Glacier distribute data across a
>   minimum of three geographically-separated Availability Zones to offer
>   the highest level of resilience to AZ loss. S3 One Zone-IA saves cost
>   by storing infrequently accessed data with lower resilience in a
>   single Availability Zone.  Amazon S3 Standard-IA is a good choice for
>   long-term storage of master data that is infrequently accessed. For
>   other infrequently accessed data, such as duplicates of backups or
>   data summaries that can be regenerated, S3 One Zone-IA provides a
>   lower price point

ps. I think they are themselves implying that one zone has lower durability.

> One Zone-IA saves cost by storing infrequently accessed data with lower resilience in a single Availability Zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that having **one** AZ instead of 2, **does** reduce the [availability](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/):

**Amazon S3 One Zone-Infrequent Access (S3 One Zone-IA)**

> Same low latency and high throughput performance of S3 Standard
>
> Designed for durability of 99.999999999% of objects in a single
> Availability Zone†
>
> Designed for 99.5% availability over a given year
>
> Backed with the Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement for availability
>
> Supports SSL for data in transit and encryption of data at rest S3
>
> Lifecycle management for automatic migration of objects to other S3
> Storage Classes

Answer (score 5):

S3 One Zone IA is just as durable from an engineering standpoint as the other storage classes *except* in the event that the availability zone where your data is stored is destroyed.

> S3 One Zone-IA offers the same high durability†, high throughput, and low latency of Amazon S3 Standard and S3 Standard-IA
>
> ...
>
> † Because S3 One Zone-IA stores data in a single AWS Availability Zone, data stored in this storage class will be lost in the event of Availability Zone destruction.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/

So, the claim being made appears to be that 1ZIA is using the same engineering design as other storage classes -- redundant storage media -- except that everything is physically in a single AZ rather than distributed across multiple zones... so it offers comparable durability... except for the case of a catastrophic event involving that AZ.

Comment: Yes but though am not an expert on probabilities and statistics I believe giving the same durability on both cases is not mathematically consistent. Either you take into account the AZ failure event probability or you don't.

Comment: I can see your point, but the durability statistics for all storage classes appear to be based on the the storage device reliability statistics, since the likelihood of *destruction* of one or more AZs is effectively impossible to calculate.  1 - (failure_probability_per_device ^ number_of_distinct_devices) is the statistical reliability, and if my napkin is correct, you can get to 11 9's with 6 devices and a failure rate of between 1% and 2%.  As long as the service isn't physically destroyed, it is highly unlikely to lose your data.  But 1ZIA is not marketed for irreplaceable data.